# How can we access to "server response" of "jqXHR" of ajaxSubmit function?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, submit, jqxhr

[ajaxSubmit](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#api) return form element. 
How can we access to "server response" of  "jqXHR" of its ajax request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        var response,xhr;
        $(form).ajaxSubmit({
            success:function (d, t, x) {                  
                response=d;
                xhr=x;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to access the `success:` event handler.

See the examples on their page: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxSubmit